# Excel/Speadsheets: How to calculate a count between the dates

Tags: excel

Have an issue when trying to count a values between the dates.
For example:
Column X date 1/1/2020
Column Y date 15/05/2020

Using formula: `=COUNTIFS(X38:X43,"<= 1/2/2020",Y38:Y43,">= 28/2/2020")`

It returns 0, but at least 1 should fit the result.

[image]

Comment: Are you certain the values are dates and not strings or another type? While it can seem awkward, adding a new pair of columns which clearly has the dates as integers may be much easier to do comparisons with.

Answer (score 3):

COUNTIFS does not like the space between the `=` and the dates.  It is trying to parse a string and with the space it is looking for a string that has a space on the front of it:

with space:

[image]

vs. without the space:

[image]

```
=COUNTIFS(X38:X43,"<=2/1/2020",Y38:Y43,">=2/28/2020")
```

Comment: Concerningly, the result using the int value is different - I wonder why

Comment: @ti7 you have the month and day reversed in the first column.

Comment: hmm - another classic prank of not using [ISO 8601](https://xkcd.com/1179/)

Comment: @ti7 BTW whether the date is stored as text or not as long as it can be converted to a date, countifs will do the parsing, so your comment above, while good practice is misleading as to what might be the issue with this question.

Comment: you're quite correct - I've updated my sheet example

Comment: Certainly so; alas, good practice isn't shouting loudly enough how much relying on such string conversion is a recipe for disaster!

Answer (score 1):

Behind the scenes, dates in Excel are just numbers, even if they are represented as dates.

You can more clearly see what is going on if the dates are shown as their integer values. (you may need to use `VALUE()` to prevent format warnings)

Note that the cell format will not change how Excel treats them in formulas.

[image: Excel Sheet]